# ORA-06413 but only in NUnit

Tags: c#, oracle, nunit

I am doing some testing using NUnit, some of which connects to an Oracle DB (Yes I realize it's not really unit testing, but it sure makes other testing easy).  I have a 64-bit machine, but everything is set to x86 and I'm using System.Data.OracleClient to do my connections. All connects and works fine using SQL Developer, the database code in a website, and a Console app running the method in question. But when I try to run it using NUnit, I get

```
ORA-06413: Connection not open
```

Most everything dealing with this error talks about having the client in the (x86) folder (which it's not), or other illegal characters in the path, which I don't see.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you running it via the NUnit app or through a VS addin like Resharper?

Comment: Throught the NUnit app, specifically the x86 exe

Comment: Not a solution, but have you considered using Oracle's client (ODP.NET) instead of System.Data.OracleClient? I know there are issues with newer Oracle versions and the .NET built-in library.

Comment: Do you have access to a 32-bit machine? If so, maybe try recreating the environment there and see if you get the same thing. That might answer the question of whether it's a 32/64 bit problem.

Comment: I probably can get one of my team members that still has a 32-bit machine to let me install things...and we were using ODP.NET but were having some issues with it so and so switched back until we can resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe NUnit-console.exe you use is written for .NET 2.0 and thus it loads CLR 2.0. That means that all other DLLs are run under CLR 2.0

http://forums.asp.net/t/1608262.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

Haha got it! It **was** an (x86) problem. It was because NUnit was running from the Program Files (x86) folder, much like the ODP.NET client would. I re-installed NUNit to my AppData folder and voila, things started working.

Answer (score 0):

I did uninstall NUnite from Program File (x86)  and reinstall NUnite to apps folder. It works for me.